# In Buddhas Time Did Kings give Freedom to His Sex Wives(Anttappura Wives)?

Tags: sexuality, life

in lord Buddhas time their was many kingdoms in India. these kingdoms had many kings. kings had many wives. some kings had 500, 1000 (Antappura) wives but they all have main 1 queen & other wives used for sex uses.most of these kings became followers of Buddhism & Buddha & they obtain nirvana (1st 3 stages as below)

1. The First Stage – Skt srotaapanna (The stream-winner)
2. The Second Stage – Sakridagamin
3. The Third Stage – Anagamin (The non-returner)

   so my question is after these became Buddhist & obtain nirvana did these kings given freedom to these Wives who use for sex uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such instance was King [Bimbisara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimbisara) giving freedom to [Khema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khema) to enter the order. Many more may be found in the cemeteries and many may not even be documented!

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is after these became Buddhist & obtain nirvana did these kings given freedom to these Wives who use for sex uses?

When one wins Nibbana one has lived the holy life and done what had to be done, i.e. one has destroyed all fetters and achieved complete security from all bondage.

One has removed the veil of ignorance permanently and therefore do not produce either wholesome or unwholesome kamma. Instead one's kamma becomes purely functional (kiriya), meaning that its no longer kammically potent and creates no further resultants (rebirth). The cittas that arise in the javana process is no longer kammically determinate since craving has been destroyed.

Since an enlightened being has destroyed all fetters and root defilements its not possible to hold other beings captured against their will or use anyone for personal gratification.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is after meeting Lord Buddha and achieving Nirvana would sex be permitted , one point I'd like to make is present day Buddhism does not condemn sex between a loving husband and wife .. But sex for the use of pleasure would be inappropriate in a secular area such as temples etc or those in  robes who take wows to abstain from many types of pleasure in the physical body also having more than one partner is kinda unfaithful too. There would be as then a certain moral code once you reach Nirvana or some enlightenment. Sorry just to clarify ...I think what you've asked is whether the Kings post enlightenment allowed their former concubines to be used for sexual pleasure? To my knowledge no body after enlightenment would approve of prostitution!

Comment: Just to clarify ...is your question  ,,,after being in the presence of Lord Buddha and reaching enlightenment would it be permissable for these wives to partake of sex ?

Comment: i'm asking here that in Buddhas time their was kings. these kings had many wives. after these kings became Buddhist (The First Stage – Skt srotaapanna (The stream-winner)
The Second Stage – Sakridagamin
The Third Stage – Anagamin (The non-returner) did these kings give freedom to his wives who used only for sex?

Comment: Yes I understand but to what extent will knowledge of this from a enlightenment point of being b useful...?